# How to add spacing to element from parent view?

Tags: ios, swiftui

I'm noob in swiftUI. I have created a subview which I'm using. In the VStack Cards(next to the car) the inside Text are not aligned with equal spacing from the left(like 150km and 38ºc are not aligned).
I want the text within the card to start after a spacing of 10 from the left of card. I have added `.padding(.left ,10)` to card but its not working. I'm attaching the code with it. Please correct me if I'm using the wrong approach.

```
struct CarInfoCard: View {
    @State var cardHeading = ""
    @State var cardUnit = ""
    @State var cardType = ""
    @State var cardNotify = false
    
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack{
           
            HStack {
                
                
                VStack(alignment: .leading){
                    
                    HStack(alignment: .lastTextBaseline, spacing: 2) {
                        Text(cardHeading)
                            .font(.system(size: 40, weight: .bold, design: .rounded))
                            .foregroundColor(Color("ColorButtonLogo"))
                        
                        Text(cardUnit)
                            .font(.system(size: 25, weight: .bold, design: .rounded))
                            .foregroundColor(Color("ColorButtonLogo"))
                    }
                    
                    
                    Text(cardType)
                        .font(.system(size: 20, design: .rounded))
                        .foregroundColor(Color("ColorButtonLogo"))
                    
                }
            }
            
        }
        .frame(width: 150, height: 90)
        .padding(.top,10)
        .padding(.bottom, 5)
//added padding to the left so that text always starts after spacing of 10. This does not work
        .padding(.leading, 10)
                
        .background(Color("ColorButton"))
        .cornerRadius(20)
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove all those redundant stacks and add alignment to frame, like (with substituted colors)

[image: demo]

```
 VStack(alignment: .leading) {    // << here one !!

      HStack(alignment: .lastTextBaseline, spacing: 2) {
            Text(cardHeading)
                 .font(.system(size: 40, weight: .bold, design: .rounded))
                 .foregroundColor(Color.blue)

            Text(cardUnit)
                 .font(.system(size: 25, weight: .bold, design: .rounded))
                 .foregroundColor(Color.blue)
      }


      Text(cardType)
            .font(.system(size: 20, design: .rounded))
            .foregroundColor(Color.blue)

 }
.frame(width: 150, height: 90, alignment: .leading)   // << here !!
.padding(.top,10)
.padding(.bottom, 5)
.padding(.leading, 10)      // now customise as needed !!
.background(Color.yellow)
.cornerRadius(20)
```